# Visual Studio Build Fails for Net Core 3.0 SDK Preview 9 on Azure Devops

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I've been struggling with this one all weekend.

I cannot obtain a successful build for Net Core 3 SDK Preview 9 (released 4 September 2019).

I have set up a pipeline solely to:

1. Use the new SDK
2. Implement a global.json file using the new SDK
3. Use Nuget 5.x and Nuget restore to correctly obtain preview packages
4. Visual Studio Build the solution

I'm getting the following errors with the build stage (4):

> Error : Unable to locate the .NET Core SDK. Check that it is installed
>   and that the version specified in global.json (if any) matches the
>   installed version.
>
> Error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' specified could not be
>   found.

I was initially getting the same error during the Nuget restore stage (3) before implementing the `global.json` in step 2, so I know the `global.json` is being correctly referenced.

**Pipeline YAML:**

```
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
  demands:
  - msbuild
  - visualstudio

steps:
- task: UseDotNet@2
  displayName: 'Use .Net Core sdk 3.0.100-preview9-014004'
  inputs:
    version: '3.0.100-preview9-014004'
    includePreviewVersions: true

- powershell: |
   $globaljson = '{"sdk": {"version": "3.0.100-preview9-014004"}}';
   $globaljson | out-file './test.app/global.json' -Encoding UTF8
  displayName: 'Global Json'

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1
  displayName: 'Use NuGet 5.x'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 5.x
    checkLatest: true

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  displayName: 'NuGet restore'
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(Parameters.solution)'

- task: VSBuild@1
  displayName: 'Build solution **\*.sln'
  inputs:
    solution: '$(Parameters.solution)'
    msbuildArgs: '/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:WebPublishMethod=Package /p:PackageAsSingleFile=true /p:SkipInvalidConfigurations=true /p:PackageLocation="$(build.artifactstagingdirectory)\\"'
    platform: '$(BuildPlatform)'
    configuration: '$(BuildConfiguration)'
```

[image]

Comment: You need to add an install job to install preview before build job in the build pipeline. I had a similar issue with preview 6.

Comment: Can you share your pipeline?

Comment: Thanks ilkerkaran. Already did that but you couldn't see without the full pipeline which has now been added.

Comment: What agent and Visual Studio you are using? AFAIK,  the .NET Core 3.0 SDK is in a prerelease state, it's not officialy supported by release Visual Studio, and the SDK team recommends using preview Visual Studios for projects that use preview SDKs. So, we may need to build this project with private agent and preview Visual Studios.

Comment: Thanks Leo, yes locally everything is fine as that's what I'm doing. Obviously this issue is on DevOps and I'm simply using the 'Latest' Visual Studio version under the Visual Studio Build configuration in the pipeline.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked for me.

Set the following variable:

```
variables:
  MSBuildSDKsPath: 'C:\\hostedtoolcache\\windows\\dotnet\\sdk\\3.0.100-preview9-014004\\sdks'
```

Set the global json

```
  - task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'Global Json'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: 'dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 3.0.100-preview9-014004'
```

Also, one thing to note, I ran into issues using `Nuget 5`. and I used `Nuget 4.7.1`.

Comment: You've nailed it Duncan. Awesome job, thanks. For the record, I only needed to add the variable. Nuget 5.x and existing Global Json powershell Yaml worked fine.

Comment: Cool. I also assume that once MSBuild 16.3 is released, this variable should not be needed.

Comment: These steps continue to work for .NET 7 preview versions.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the comments you need to install .net core preview 9 before you can use it.

You need to put the code below before your use statement:

```
- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Install .net core 3.0 (preview)'
  inputs:
            version: '3.0.100-preview9-014004'
```

Hope this helps. I use this yml to build on azure devops.
I 'forgot' the global.json - added it and it worked.

**Update: More from my working pipeline script**

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-latest'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'
steps:
- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Install .net core 3.0 (preview)'
  inputs:
    version: '3.0.100-preview9-014004'

- task: NuGetToolInstaller@1

- task: NuGetCommand@2
  inputs:
    restoreSolution: '$(solution)'
```

azure-pipelines.yml and global.json are in the root of my project folder.

Comment: Thanks SamuelD, Same error I'm afraid. The UseDotNet@2 task is installing the SDK fine and the nuget restore is working nicely with it. It's just the VS build step failing and obviously not see the SDK like Nuget Restore does. My gut feel is that this is a Preview 9 issue. Preview 8 was building fine.

Comment: You get an error of the fialing VS Build? Are you sure you are on Visual studio 2019 preview Version 16.3.0 preview 3? I had a failing updater and needed to download the new version (i thought it was on 3 but it wasn't).

Comment: Sorry SamuelD, I only have the option for 'Latest' in the pipeline step. No ability to use a Preview. Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you see in Visual studio > Help > About Microsoft visual studio?

Comment: It's DevOps SamuelD, not local. That's where the confusion is. Locally I can build absolutely fine using Visual Studio and enabling Previewing of Net Core SDKs.

Comment: SamuelD, I've added the screenshot above from Azure DevOps.

Comment: I added this task for updating the global.json:
  
```- task: PowerShell@2
    displayName: 'dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 3.0.100-preview9-014004'
    inputs:
      targetType: 'inline'
      script: 'dotnet new globaljson --sdk-version 3.0.100-preview9-014004'
```

Comment: I am currently having this error when trying this approach:
Error MSB4236: The SDK 'Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web' specified could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

.Net Core 3.0 is finally released. You just have to install **.Net Core 3.0.100** as a first step:

```
- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Install .net core 3.0.100'
  inputs:
    version: '3.0.100'
```

Full `.yml` file with test and artifacts publish. Update this `'FolderName/ProjectName.csproj'` before running this.

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

variables:
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: DotNetCoreInstaller@0
  displayName: 'Install .net core 3.0.100'
  inputs:
    version: '3.0.100'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  inputs:
    command: test
    projects: '**/*Test/*.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration)'

- script: dotnet build --configuration $(buildConfiguration)
  displayName: 'dotnet build $(buildConfiguration)'

- task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: 'dotnet publish --configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
  inputs:
    command: publish
    publishWebProjects: false
    projects: 'FolderName/ProjectName.csproj'
    arguments: '--configuration $(buildConfiguration) --output $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'
    zipAfterPublish: true

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'publish artifacts'
```